# Is it possible to manipulate a character voice back to the original recording?

Tags: audacity, voice-over, voice-manipulation

I have to create 3 original character voices, for my animation.

Question:

If I just record my casual voice, and manipulate it in three different ways with Audacity, would it be possible for someone to easily manipulate the three voices with the same software back to my original voice by just de-applying the obvious effects?

---

(I don't want that to happen, because i have a voice of a delinquent, despite the fact that i'm not a delinquent.

My momentary situation limits me to Audacity.

It seems that in theory and in practice it should be possible to get one's original voice by de-applying the same effects they applied. I'm a beginner in voice/audio and I'm not sure if someone well versed in this would be able to get my original voice back quite swiftly.

My other option is creating 3 original voices before i even run a voice SW, and tweak them further if necessary, however the decision which option I will take partly depends on the answer to this question. I thank you in advance for any guidance.)

Comment: if you are manipulating the voice significantly, it would be very difficult (though not impossible) for this to be reverse-engineered.

Comment: Is your concern truly that it could be reverse engineered, thus giving away your Clark Kent persona… or that you're uncertain about how to approach the different characterisations?

Answer (score -2):

It would be hard in audacity.  Perhaps you can find some plug ins to do it if they were really simple.

Reversing effects is usually so difficult that only the CIA can afford to try to achieve that result.  Effects are usually combinations of things with several variables in each effect.  Reversing that is not easy.

Your effects could be too simple so that more folks could conceivably reverse engineer them.  But I would not be losing sleep over it.

What are you afraid of anyway?

Comment: Whether you perceive the answer to be correct or not probably isn't the issue. It's the confrontational approach you are adopting to the OP which is gaining you the down-vote. Again, you are being down-voted by a community based on their opinion of your answer, nothing more, nothing less. If you perceive this to be 'bullying' from 'cowards' maybe this isn't the right place for you to share your 50 years of experience. On the other hand, if you are prepared to share your experience in a non-confrontational way, with quality answers, you are likely to get up-voted. Your choice entirely.